# Unity5 2D Проверка соприкосновений

Tags: unity3d-android, unity3d-editor, unity3d-ui, unity3d

Значит я делаю небольшую головоломку. Суть такая - нужно наложить квадрат на квадрат, чтобы получился определенный цвет. Проблема в том что я не могу отследить наложение (*соприкосновение*) этих квадратов. Пробовал **OnTriggerEnter2D**, **OnCollisionEnter2D**, ничего не работает(код функции не выполняется)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У обоих объектов должен быть компонент Collider, как минимум у одного из объектов должен быть компонент Rigidbody.

OnCollisionEnter срабатывает при соприкосновении коллайдеров с выключенными триггерами, OnTriggerEnter - наоборот.

[Здесь](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) все черным по белому описано на русском

Comment: Спасибо, помогло